# Bar/Chart diagrams generation in PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, statistics, diagram

Anyone has a suggestion how you could create Bar/Chart-Diagrams in PDF (with Prawn f.e) in Ruby on Rails?

I didn't found any usefull information in google.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) for charts to generate SVG based elements and would use [Prawn gem](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) for generating pages in PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

[wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is a pretty robust open source x-platform tool that lets you convert any web page to pdf.

my experience of it is that it works very well

then you've got your pick of charting javascript frameworks or server side charts

here's a [gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/wkhtmltopdf)

Answer (score 1):

wkhtmltopdf is now at [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (with sourcecode at [github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) )

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://github.com/fullscreen/squid – a Ruby library to plot charts in PDF files